# Regex for bunch of choices without any order

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a JAVA regex to test if specific options are set. At the moment I have `[ks]?[zx]?[ap]?` so it is either k, s or nothing, then z, x or nothing and at last a, p or nothing.

The only problem with this regex is it works only in this one order but it should work with all orders, because `kza`, `azk`, `zka`, `kaz`, `akz` and `zak` do the same thing.

Comment: Why do you use regex for this? Just use loop and define some flags (which can be OR together) to indicate the choice of options.

Comment: Could you give more information on the problem? there are numerous solutions to this, and the best one won't be obvious till the whole situation is laid out...

Comment: I simply want to test if for each “pair of options” (k or s; z or x; a or p) only one (or none) option is selected. For example the option “zx” makes no sense as each option would replace the other one. Sure I could simply iterate through this, but I thought there is maybe a cool regex to simply check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steel yourself - this answer reinforces regular expressions as a write-only language!

```regex
^(([ks](?!.*[ks]))|([zx](?!.*[zx]))|([ap](?!.*[ap]))){0,3}$
```

This can more clearly be written like so if you're using Groovy (or Java 7) for multi-line strings:

```regex
^(?x:
    (  (  [ks]  (?!.*[ks])  )
    |  (  [zx]  (?!.*[zx])  )
    |  (  [ap]  (?!.*[ap])  )
    )  {0,3}
)$
```

This version matches each group, only if that group doesn't appear somewhere later on in the string. This is a 'zero width, look ahead assertion'.

Comment: `"azp"` or `"aza"` matches the regex, but it seems that it shouldn't.

Comment: @nhahtdh Ahhh, you're right. I thing I've solved it though, by adding the `.*` in the look ahead assertions.

Comment: I love regular expressions, but, as a wise man once said, "Sometimes you have a programming problem and it seems like the best solution is to use regular expressions; now you have two problems."

Comment: @DamianPowell Have you ever looked at REBOL?  Specifically its parse function.  You might dig that.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood, replace '?' by a 'pipe' : try :`"[ks]|[zx]|[ap]"`